# JQuery changing color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I am having a really silly trouble with the click function on jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/icoltus/BdQU2/330/

```
$('#1').click(function () {
         $('#hola').className = '';
         $('#hola').addClass('green');
     });
     $('#2').click(function () {

         $('#hola').className = '';
         $('#hola').addClass('orange');
     });
```

The purpose of the code is that whenever you click on one ball the text color changes, right now I have this error:

If you click on ball number 3 the text will change its color, then if you click on ball number 2 the text color won't change; after that, if you click on ball number 4 the text will change its color, then if you click on ball number 3 the text color won't change (I think you get what the problem is)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `.removeClass();` instead of `.className = '';`

Comment: Alejandro Cordoba  please check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on the solved code: http://jsfiddle.net/32majraq/2/

You could set data-color attributes to each of the spans like this:

```
<div class="greenLine">
            <span data-color="green"></span>
            <span data-color='orange'></span>
            <span data-color='blue'></span>
            <span data-color='brown'></span>
            <span data-color='black'></span>
            <span data-color='red'></span>
            <span data-color='purple'></span>
            <span data-color='pink'></span>
            <span data-color='grey'></span>
        </div>
    <div id="hola">JHola</div>
```

And then you could get the data-color value from them and do what you want, only 7 lines of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let allSpans = $('.greenLine span');
  allSpans.on('click', function(){
    $('#hola').removeClass(); //Remove the class added before to add another
    $('#hola').addClass($(this).attr('data-color'))
  });

});
```

### **UPDATE**

As [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519416/martijn) said, all classes will be removed, so I made another code that fixes this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/32majraq/4/

```
let addedBefore = undefined;
$(document).ready(function(){
  let allSpans = $('.greenLine span');

  allSpans.on('click', function(){
    if(addedBefore !== undefined)
        $('#hola').removeClass(addedBefore);

    addedBefore = $(this).attr('data-color');
    $('#hola').addClass(addedBefore);
  });

});
```

Comment: Nor do I. +1 as this solution is more elegant than most :)

Comment: Haha, even referenced your answer in mine

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is (in my opinion) the most elegant solution!

Comment: @AlejandroCordoba no need of id then. so try to remove it from your html

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to do it in the more advanced way. using HTML5's attribute `data`

**HTML**

```
<div class="greenLine">
  <span class="1" data-value="green"></span>
  <span id="2" data-value="orange"></span>
  <span id="3" data-value="blue"></span>
  <span id="4" data-value="brown"></span>
  <span id="5" data-value="black"></span>
  <span id="6" data-value="red"></span>
  <span id="7" data-value="purple"></span>
  <span id="8" data-value="pink"></span>
  <span id="9" data-value="grey"></span>
</div>
<div id="hola">JHola</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.greenLine>span').click(function() {
     var getclass = $(this).data('value');
     $('#hola').removeClass().addClass(getclass);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/princesodhi/xLt63808/

Answer (score 1):

Your current logic isn't optimal. ***You should not clear all classes***. The reason that this isn't a good idea, is that if you use `.remove()` or `.clasname=''` to remove all classes, you also remove (future) relevant classes which have nothing to do with the colors.

This might not be a problem now, but this way of thinking will get you into trouble in the future. Also, when another programmer will work on code like this, they will ***not*** expect this type of behaviour.

*For example, say you want to add a new color, you're going to have to alter your remove classes to match the new color. Or relevent classes not related to the colors will also be removed and require a weird workaround.*

---

Instead of adding and removing classes, you could try a different approach:  You can set `data-*` values in html, and you can also css it:

```
$('#1').click(function () {
     $('#hola').data('color','green');
});
$('#2').click(function () {
     $('#hola').data('color','orange');
});
```

Now you can add css to match this:

```
[data-color="green"]{  background:green; }
[data-color="orange"]{ background:orange; }
```

You could combine this with the answer by [masterjohn12](http://Instead%20of%20adding%20and%20removing%20classes,%20you%20could%20try%20a%20different%20approach.), instead of using all the ID's, use the select+data attribute for values.

Comment: At SO it is courtacy to explain why you dontvote so a poster may improve their asnwer...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll keep them in mind for future coding! Good way of thinking.

Comment: @Varin No one uses IE6

Comment: Maybe the second programmer working on this code is using it.

Comment: What kind of programmer/designer uses old browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, and jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BdQU2/335/

Also, the first span had class="1" instead of the id="1".

using `.removeClass()` without parameter, gets rid of all the classes.

```js
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#1').click(function () {
             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('green');
             
         });
         $('#2').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('orange');
         });
          $('#3').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('blue');
         });
          $('#4').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('brown');
         });
          $('#5').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('black');
         });
          $('#6').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('red');
         });
          $('#7').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('purple');
         });
          $('#8').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('pink');
         });
          $('#9').click(function () {

             $('#hola').removeClass();
             $('#hola').addClass('grey');
         });
     });
```

```css
.greenLine {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #24cda3;
    height: 8px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.greenLine span {
    top: -8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(1) {
    left: -1%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(2) {
    left: 12.5%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(3) {
    left: 25%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(4) {
    left: 37.5%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(5) {
    left: 50%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(6) {
    left: 62.5%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(7) {
    left: 75%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(8) {
    left: 87.5%;
}
.greenLine span:nth-child(9) {
    left: 98.5%;
}

#hola {
   color:wheat;
}
#hola.green {
    color:green;
}
#hola.orange {
    color:orange;
}
#hola.blue {
    color: blue;
}
#hola.brown {
    color: brown;
}
#hola.black {
    color:brown;
}
#hola.red {
    color: red;
}
#hola.purple {
    color:purple;
}
#hola.pink {
    color: pink;
}
#hola.grey {
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="greenLine">
            <span id="1"></span>
            <span id="2"></span>
            <span id="3"></span>
            <span id="4"></span>
            <span id="5"></span>
            <span id="6"></span>
            <span id="7"></span>
            <span id="8"></span>
            <span id="9"></span>
        </div>
<div id="hola">JHola</div>
```

Comment: Please dont do this. If you have other relevent classes, you will remove them all. Another programmer working on this code will **not** expect this.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no other classes on this particular element and it's referenced as an id so it won't affect anything else

Comment: There are no other classes *now*, but maybe in the future you want to add class `example` (for whatever reason). Then, when this code is implemented, you will remove that class. Code should be prepared for the future :)

Comment: With the example which was provided, this is a good solution. If I was that worried about what will happen with my code in the future, I'd never write anything as there is always something that could prevent something else in the future.

Comment: No, IMO it is a solution, not a good solution. A good solution doesn't only answer the question, but will also help understand future problems, or explain potential logic flaws :)

Comment: But it will work on IE6 so it is very much backwards compatible, unlike using data attributes which will only work in browsers supporting HTML5.